# html remove space from table row

Tags: html, css, html-table

I want to create a 3 x 3 table with no spaces in between the the rows AND columns.
At the moment, I set cellspacing and cellpadding both to zero, but I still get some space between the rows. I posted a picture of what it looks like. See the space between the rows? How do I get rid of that?

[image: I posted an image of what the space between the rows]

Okay here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" >

    <tr >
       <td><img src="bgimage.png" /></td>
       <td><img src="bgimage.png" /></td>
       <td><img src="bgimage.png" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr >
      <td><img src="bgimage.png" /></td>
      <td><img src="bgimage.png" /></td>
      <td><img src="bgimage.png" /></td>
   </tr>
   <tr >
     <td><img src="bgimage.png" /></td>
     <td><img src="bgimage.png" /></td>
     <td><img src="bgimage.png" /></td>
  </tr>
 </table>
```

Any help in removing the space between the rows would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Set line-height:0  for the td..                                   http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/fFeY4/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can try and add this to your CSS:

```
td {
  line-height: 0;    
}​
```

should solve it.

Comment: Wow. Thank you! Adding keywords here for others looking to fix the same issue I have been struggling with: d3 svg height property hidden space margin padding in table row tr ...

Comment: I used <td align=center style="line-height:0.7;"> on a single td and it worked! Thanks :)